# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare fputcsv()

Tags: php, function, fputcsv

I have found a php inventory  http://inventory-management.org/ easy but was written in PHP4? and I run now on PHP5. I have found some errors that I have already managed to fix but they are keep coming up so I would like to see if I can managed to run at the end. (As it is really simple script only has 5-7 php files).

Could someone help me please how to fix this error?

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare fputcsv() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventory\lib\common.php on line 935

which is:

```
function fputcsv ($fp, $array, $deliminator=",") {
    return fputs($fp, putcsv($array,$delimitator));
}#end fputcsv()
```

here is the full code:

```
<?php
/*
*/

    /**
    * description returns an array with filename base name and the extension
    *
    * @param filemane format
    *
    * @return array
    *
    * @access public
    */
    function FileExt($filename) {

        //checking if the file have an extension
        if (!strstr($filename, "."))
            return array("0"=>$filename,"1"=>"");

        //peoceed to normal detection

        $filename = strrev($filename);

        $extpos = strpos($filename , ".");

        $file = strrev(substr($filename , $extpos + 1));
        $ext = strrev(substr($filename ,  0 , $extpos));

        return array("0"=>$file,"1"=>$ext);
    }

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function UploadFile($source, $destination , $name ="") {
    $name = $name ? $name : basename($source);
    $name = FileExt($name);
    $name[2]= $name[0];

    $counter = 0 ;
    while (file_exists( $destination . $name[0] . "." . $name[1] )) {
        $name[0] = $name[2] . $counter;
        $counter ++;
    }

    copy($source , $destination . $name[0] . "." . $name[1] );
    @chmod($destination . $name[0] . "." . $name[1] , 0777);
}

function UploadFileFromWeb($source, $destination , $name) {
    $name = FileExt($name);
    $name[2]= $name[0];

    $counter = 0 ;
    while (file_exists( $destination . $name[0] . "." . $name[1] )) {
        $name[0] = $name[2] . $counter;
        $counter ++;
    }

    SaveFileContents($destination . $name[0] . "." . $name[1] , $source);
    @chmod($destination . $name[0] . "." . $name[1] , 0777);
}


/**
* returns the contents of a file in a string
*
* @param string $file_name  name of file to be loaded
*
* @return string
*
* @acces public
*/
function GetFileContents($file_name) {
//  if (!file_exists($file_name)) {
//      return null;
//  }

    //echo "<br>:" . $file_name;
    $file = fopen($file_name,"r");

    //checking if the file was succesfuly opened
    if (!$file)
        return null;

    if (strstr($file_name,"://"))
        while (!feof($file))
            $result .= fread($file,1024);
    else
        $result = @fread($file,filesize($file_name));

    fclose($file);

    return $result;
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function SaveFileContents($file_name,$content) {
//  echo $file_name;
    $file = fopen($file_name,"w");
    fwrite($file,$content);
    fclose($file);
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function Debug($what,$pre = 1,$die = 0) {
    if (PB_DEBUG_EXT == 1) {
        if ($pre == 1)
            echo "<pre style=\"background-color:white;\">";

        print_r($what);

        if ($pre == 1)
            echo "</pre>";

        if ($die == 1)
            die;
    }
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function SendMail($to,$from,$subject,$message,$to_name,$from_name) {    
    if ($to_name)
        $to = "$to_name <$to>";

    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    if ($from_name) {
        $headers .= "From: $from_name <$from>\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_name <$from>\n";
    }
    else {
        $headers .= "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $from\n";
    }

    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

    return mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);      
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function FillVars($var,$fields,$with) {
    $fields = explode (",",$fields);

    foreach ($fields as $field)
        if (!$var[$field])
            !$var[$field] = $with;

    return $var;
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function CleanupString($string,$strip_tags = TRUE) {
    $string = addslashes(trim($string));

    if ($strip_tags)
        $string = strip_tags($string);

    return $string;
}

define("RX_EMAIL","^[a-z0-9]+([_\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}$");
define("RX_CHARS","[a-z\ ]");
define("RX_DIGITS","[0-9]"); 
define("RX_ALPHA","[^a-z0-9_]");
define("RX_ZIP","[0-9\-]"); 
define("RX_PHONE","[0-9\-\+\(\)]");

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function CheckString($string,$min,$max,$regexp = "",$rx_result = FALSE) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 0)
        $string = CleanupString($string);

    if (strlen($string) < $min)
        return 1;
    elseif (($max != 0) && (strlen($string) > $max))
        return 2;
    elseif ($regexp != "")
        if ($rx_result == eregi($regexp,$string))
            return 3;

    return 0;
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*///  FIRST_NAME:S:3:60,LAST_NAME:S...
function ValidateVars($source,$vars) {
    $vars = explode(",",$vars);

    foreach ($vars as $var) {
        list($name,$type,$min,$max) = explode(":",$var);

        switch ($type) {
            case "S":
                $type = RX_CHARS;
                $rx_result = FALSE;
            break;

            case "I":
                $type = RX_DIGITS;
                $rx_result = TRUE;
            break;

            case "E":
                $type = RX_EMAIL;
                $rx_result = FALSE;
            break;

            case "P":
                $type = RX_PHONE;
                $rx_result = TRUE;
            break;

            case "Z":
                $type = RX_ZIP;
                $rx_result = FALSE;
            break;

            case "A":
                $type = "";
            break;

            case "F":
                //experimental crap
                $type = RX_ALPHA;
                $rx_result = TRUE;
                //$source[strtolower($name)] = str_replace(" ", "" , $source[strtolower($name)] );
            break;

        }
        //var_dump($result);
        if (($result = CheckString($source[strtolower($name)],$min,$max,$type,$rx_result)) != 0)
            $errors[] = $name;

    }   

    return is_array($errors) ? $errors : 0;
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function ResizeImage($source,$destination,$size) {
    if (PB_IMAGE_MAGICK == 1)
        system( PB_IMAGE_MAGICK_PATH . "convert $source -resize {$size}x{$size} $destination");
    else
        copy($source,$destination);
}

/**
* uses microtime() to return the current unix time w/ microseconds
*
* @return float the current unix time in the form of seconds.microseconds
*
* @access public
*/
function GetMicroTime() {
    list($usec,$sec) = explode(" ",microtime());

    return (float) $usec + (float) $sec;
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function GetArrayPart($input,$from,$count) {
    $return = array();
    $max = count($input);

    for ($i = $from; $i < $from + $count; $i++ ) 
        if ($i<$max)
            $return[] = $input[$i];

    return $return; 
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function ReplaceAllImagesPath($htmldata,$image_path) {
    $htmldata = stripslashes($htmldata);
    // replacing  IE formating style
    $htmldata = str_replace("<IMG","<img",$htmldata);
    // esmth, i dont know why i'm doing
    preg_match_all("'<img.*?>'si",$htmldata,$images);

//<?//ing edit plus

    foreach ($images[0] as $image)
        $htmldata = str_replace($image,ReplaceImagePath($image,$image_path),$htmldata);

    return $htmldata;//implode("\n",$html_out);
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function ReplaceImagePath($image,$replace) {
    // removing tags
    $image = stripslashes($image);
    $image = str_replace("<","",$image);
    $image = str_replace(">","",$image);

    // exploging image in proprietes
    $image_arr = explode(" ",$image);
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($image_arr) ;$i++ ) {
        if (stristr($image_arr[$i],"src")) {
            // lets it :]
            $image_arr[$i] = explode("=",$image_arr[$i]);
            // modifing the image path
            // i doing this

            // replacing ',"
            $image_arr[$i][1] = str_replace("'","",$image_arr[$i][1]);
            $image_arr[$i][1] = str_replace("\"","",$image_arr[$i][1]);

            //getting only image name
            $image_arr[$i][1] = strrev(substr(strrev($image_arr[$i][1]),0,strpos(strrev($image_arr[$i][1]),"/")));

            // building the image back
            $image_arr[$i][1] = "\"" . $replace . $image_arr[$i][1] . "\"";
            $image_arr[$i] = implode ("=",$image_arr[$i]);
        }       
    }   
    // adding tags
    return "<" . implode(" ",$image_arr) . ">";
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function DowloadAllImages($images,$path) {  
    foreach ($images as $image)
        @SaveFileContents($path ."/".ExtractFileNameFromPath($image),@implode("",@file($image)));   
}


function GetAllImagesPath($htmldata) {
    $htmldata = stripslashes($htmldata);
    // replacing  IE formating style
    $htmldata = str_replace("<IMG","<img",$htmldata);
    // esmth, i dont know why i'm doing
    preg_match_all("'<img.*?>'si",$htmldata,$images);

//<?//ing edit plus

    foreach ($images[0] as $image)
        $images_path[] = GetImageName($image);

    return $images_path;
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function GetImagePath($image) {
    // removing tags
    $image = stripslashes($image);
    $image = str_replace("<","",$image);
    $image = str_replace(">","",$image);

    // exploging image in proprietes
    $image_arr = explode(" ",$image);
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($image_arr) ;$i++ ) {
        if (stristr($image_arr[$i],"src")) {
            // lets it :]
            $image_arr[$i] = explode("=",$image_arr[$i]);
            // modifing the image path
            // i doing this

            // replacing ',"
            $image_arr[$i][1] = str_replace("'","",$image_arr[$i][1]);
            $image_arr[$i][1] = str_replace("\"","",$image_arr[$i][1]);

            return strrev(substr(strrev($image_arr[$i][1]),0,strpos(strrev($image_arr[$i][1]),"/")));;
        }       
    }   
    // adding tags
    return "";
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function GetImageName($image) {
    // removing tags
    $image = stripslashes($image);
    $image = str_replace("<","",$image);
    $image = str_replace(">","",$image);

    // exploging image in proprietes
    $image_arr = explode(" ",$image);
    for ($i = 0;$i < count($image_arr) ;$i++ ) {
        if (stristr($image_arr[$i],"src")) {
            // lets it :]
            $image_arr[$i] = explode("=",$image_arr[$i]);
            // modifing the image path
            // i doing this

            // replacing ',"
            $image_arr[$i][1] = str_replace("'","",$image_arr[$i][1]);
            $image_arr[$i][1] = str_replace("\"","",$image_arr[$i][1]);

            return $image_arr[$i][1];
        }       
    }   
    // adding tags
    return "";
}

/**
* reinventing the wheel [badly]
*
* @param somthin
*
* @return erroneous
*
* @access denied
*/
function ExtractFileNameFromPath($file) {
    //return strrev(substr(strrev($file),0,strpos(strrev($file),"/")));

    // sau ai putea face asha. umpic mai smart ca mai sus dar tot stupid
    // daca le dai path fara slashes i.e. un filename prima returneaza "" asta taie primu char
    //return substr($file,strrpos($file,"/") + 1,strlen($file) - strrpos($file,"/"));

    // corect ar fi cred asha [observa smart usage`u de strRpos]
    //return substr($file,strrpos($file,"/") + (strstr($file,"/") ? 1 : 0),strlen($file) - strrpos($file,"/"));

    // sau putem folosi tactica `nute mai caca pe tine and rtm' shi facem asha
    return basename($file);

    // har har :]]
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function RemoveArraySlashes($array) {
    if ($array)     
        foreach ($array as $key => $item)
            if (is_array($item)) 
                $array[$key] = RemoveArraySlashes($item);
            else        
                $array[$key] = stripslashes($item);

    return $array;
}

function AddArraySlashes($array) {
    if ($array)     
        foreach ($array as $key => $item)
            if (is_array($item)) 
                $array[$key] = AddArraySlashes($item);
            else        
                $array[$key] = addslashes($item);

    return $array;
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function Ahtmlentities($array) {
    if (is_array($array))       
        foreach ($array as $key => $item)
            if (is_array($item)) 
                $array[$key] = ahtmlentities($item);
            else        
                $array[$key] = htmlentities(stripslashes($item),ENT_COMPAT);
    else
        return htmlentities(stripslashes($array),ENT_COMPAT);

    return $array;
}

function AStripSlasshes($array) {
    if (is_array($array))       
        foreach ($array as $key => $item)
            if (is_array($item)) 
                $array[$key] = AStripSlasshes($item);
            else        
                $array[$key] = stripslashes($item);
    else
        return stripslashes($array);

    return $array;
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function Ahtml_entity_decode($array) {
    if ($array) 
        foreach ($array as $key => $item)
            if (is_array($item))
                $array[$key] = ahtml_entity_decode($item);
            else        
                $array[$key] = html_entity_decode($item,ENT_COMPAT);

    return $array;
}


function array2xml ($name, $value, $indent = 1)
{
 $indentstring = "\t";
 for ($i = 0; $i < $indent; $i++)
 {
   $indentstring .= $indentstring;
 }
 if (!is_array($value))
 {
   $xml = $indentstring.'<'.$name.'>'.$value.'</'.$name.'>'."\n";
 }
 else
 {
   if($indent === 1)
   {
     $isindex = False;
   }
   else
   {
     $isindex = True;
     while (list ($idxkey, $idxval) = each ($value))
     {
       if ($idxkey !== (int)$idxkey)
       {
         $isindex = False;
       }
     }
   }

   reset($value);  
   while (list ($key, $val) = each ($value))
   {
     if($indent === 1)
     {
       $keyname = $name;
       $nextkey = $key;
     }
     elseif($isindex)
     {
       $keyname = $name;
       $nextkey = $name;
     }
     else
     {
       $keyname = $key;
       $nextkey = $key;
     }
     if (is_array($val))
     {
       $xml .= $indentstring.'<'.$keyname.'>'."\n";
       $xml .= array2xml ($nextkey, $val, $indent+1);
       $xml .= $indentstring.'</'.$keyname.'>'."\n";
     }
     else
     {
       $xml .= array2xml ($nextkey, $val, $indent);
     }
   }
 }
 return $xml;
}


function GetPhpContent($file) {
    if (file_exists($file) ) {
        $data = GetFileContents($file);

        //replacing special chars in content
        $data = str_replace("<?php","",$data);
        $data = str_replace("?>","",$data);

        return $data;
    }
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function KeyArray($array,$recurse = 0 , $count = 1) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            $array[$key]["key"] = $count ++;

            if ($recurse) {
                foreach ($array[$key] as $k => $val)
                    if (is_array($val)) {
                        KeyArray($array[$key][$k] , $recurse , $count);
                    }                                                   
            }           
        }       
    }

    return $count + 1;
}


function RandomWord( $passwordLength ) {
    $password = "";
    for ($index = 1; $index <= $passwordLength; $index++) {
         // Pick random number between 1 and 62
         $randomNumber = rand(1, 62);
         // Select random character based on mapping.
         if ($randomNumber < 11)
              $password .= Chr($randomNumber + 48 - 1); // [ 1,10] => [0,9]
         else if ($randomNumber < 37)
              $password .= Chr($randomNumber + 65 - 10); // [11,36] => [A,Z]
         else
              $password .= Chr($randomNumber + 97 - 36); // [37,62] => [a,z]
    }
    return $password;
}

function DeleteFolder($file) {
 if (file_exists($file)) {
   chmod($file,0777);
   if (is_dir($file)) {
     $handle = opendir($file); 
     while($filename = readdir($handle)) {
       if ($filename != "." && $filename != "..") {
         DeleteFolder($file."/".$filename);
       }
     }
     closedir($handle);
     rmdir($file);
   } else {
     unlink($file);
   }
 }
}

    function GenerateRecordID($array) {
        $max = 0;
        if (is_array($array)) {
            foreach ($array as $key => $val)
                $max = ($key > $max ? $key : $max);

            return $max + 1;
        }
        else return 1;
    }



/*****************************************************

Links cripting for admin

DO NOT TOUCH UNLKESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING


*****************************************************/

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function CryptLink($link) {

    if (defined("PB_CRYPT_LINKS") && (PB_CRYPT_LINKS == 1)) {

        if (stristr($link,"javascript:")) {
/*          if (stristr($link,"window.location=")) {
                $pos = strpos($link , "window.location=");
                $js = substr($link , 0 , $pos + 17 );
                $final = substr($link , $pos + 17 );
                $final = substr($final, 0, strlen($final) - 1 );

                //well done ... crypt the link now
                $url = @explode("?" , $final);

                if (!is_array($url))
                    $url[0] = $final;

                $tmp = str_replace( $url[0] . "?" , "" , $final);   
                $uri = urlencode(urlencode(base64_encode(str_rot13($tmp))));
                $link = $js . $url[0] . "?" . $uri . md5($uri) . "'";
            }
*/
        } else {

            $url = @explode("?" , $link);

            if (!is_array($url))
                $url[0] = $link;

            $tmp = str_replace( $url[0] . "?" , "" , $link);    
            $uri = urlencode(urlencode(base64_encode(str_rot13($tmp))));
            $link = $url[0] . "?" . $uri . md5($uri);
        }
    }   

    return $link;
}

/************************************************************************/
/* SOME PREINITIALISATION CRAP*/



if (defined("PB_CRYPT_LINKS") && (PB_CRYPT_LINKS == 1) ) {
    $key = key($_GET);

    if (is_array($_GET) && (count($_GET) == 1) && ($_GET[$key] == "")) {

        $tmp = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
        //do the md5 check
        $md5 = substr($tmp , -32);
        $tmp = substr($tmp , 0 , strlen($tmp) - 32);

        if ($md5 != md5($tmp)) {
            //header("index.php?action=badrequest");
            //exit;
            die("Please dont change the links!");
        }

        $tmp = str_rot13(base64_decode(urldecode(urldecode($tmp))));

        $tmp_array = @explode("&" , $tmp);
        $tmp_array = is_array($tmp_array) ? $tmp_array : array($tmp);

        if (is_array($tmp_array)) {
            foreach ($tmp_array as $key => $val) {
                $tmp2 = explode("=" , $val);
                $out[$tmp2[0]] = $tmp2[1];
            }               
        } else {
            $tmp2 = explode("=" , $tmp);
            $out[$tmp2[0]] = $tmp2[1];
        }

        $_GET = $out;
    }   
}

/***********************************************************************/


function ArrayReplace($what , $with , $array ) {
    if ($array) 
        foreach ($array as $key => $item)
            if (is_array($item))
                $array[$key] = ArrayReplace($what , $with , $item);
            else        
                $array[$key] = str_replace($what , $with , $item);

    return $array;
}

function stri_replace( $find, $replace, $string )
{
   $parts = explode( strtolower($find), strtolower($string) );
   $pos = 0;
   foreach( $parts as $key=>$part ){
       $parts[ $key ] = substr($string, $pos, strlen($part));
       $pos += strlen($part) + strlen($find);
       }
   return( join( $replace, $parts ) );
}

/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function GMTDate($format , $date) {
    global $_GMT;
    return date($format , $date - $_GMT);
}

function putcsv ($array, $deliminator=",") {
    $line = "";
    foreach($array as $val) {
        # remove any windows new lines, 
        # as they interfere with the parsing at the other end
        $val = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $val);
        # if a deliminator char, a double quote char or a newline 
        # are in the field, add quotes
        if(ereg("[$deliminator\"\n\r]", $val)) {
             $val = '"'.str_replace('"', '""', $val).'"';
        }#end if
        $line .= $val.$deliminator;
    }#end foreach
    # strip the last deliminator 
    $line = substr($line, 0, (strlen($deliminator) * -1));
    # add the newline 
    $line .= "\n";
    # we don't care if the file pointer is invalid, 
    # let fputs take care of it
    return $line;
}#end fputcsv()

function fputcsv ($fp, $array, $deliminator=",") {
    return fputs($fp, putcsv($array,$delimitator));
}#end fputcsv()


/**
* description
*
* @param
*
* @return
*
* @access
*/
function is_subaction($sub,$action) {
    return (bool)($_GET["sub"] == $sub) && ($_GET["action"] == $action);
}


?>
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove that definition of fputcsv() and let PHP's built-in fputcsv() function do the work.... the arguments are the same

Comment: But if you're having such problems with upgrading an antiquated script from PHP4 to PHP5, don't you think that perhaps you should look for a PHP5 script in the first place

Comment: I tried, however even stackoverflow recommended to check online tutorials but I could not find any. Although it is working now I just need to test it fully:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fputcsv()`](https://www.php.net/fputcsv) is a built in PHP function. This means you *cannot* name your own function the same thing.

If you need this code to work with PHP4, just check to see if the [function exists](https://www.php.net/function_exists) first, then if not, create your own.

```
if (!function_exists('fputcsv')) {
     // Your definition here
}
```