# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare function

Tags: php, function

I've a problem, with this function.

How can solve this?

---

**My Code:**

```
// Buscar Tema
$guardardato = array();

foreach($html->find('table', 2)->find('tr') as $datossc) {
    $title = $datossc->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
    if ($title != 'Song Title') {

        $guardardato[0] = $title;

        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(-)", " - ", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(:)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "([0-9]+)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(Current Song)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(pista)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(pista)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(www.[a-z]+.com.ar)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(www.[a-z]+.com)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(www.[a-z]+.net)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "([a-z]+.com.ar)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "([a-z]+.com)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "([a-z]+.net)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = ucwords(strtolower($guardardato[0]));

        function obtener($guardardato) {
            foreach ($guardardato as $k => $v){
                return $v;
            }
        }
        print obtener($guardardato);
    }
}
```

---

**Error:**

> **Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare obtener() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs...\index.php:43) in **C:\xampp\htdocs...\index.php** on line **43**

---

**Line 43:**

```
function obtener($guardardato) {
```

---

I try with [this posible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21831732/3187989) but thats does work.

Can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple: You can't declare a function twice with the same name!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function definition (`function obtener($guardardato)`) is nested inside of your `foreach` loop, so every time it loops through an item in the array it will try to redefine the function `obtener`.

To fix this simply move your function outside of the `foreach` loop like so:

```
function obtener($guardardato) {
    foreach ($guardardato as $k => $v){
        return $v;
    }
}

// Buscar Tema
$guardardato = array();

foreach($html->find('table', 2)->find('tr') as $datossc) {
    $title = $datossc->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
    if ($title != 'Song Title') {

        $guardardato[0] = $title;

        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(-)", " - ", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(:)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "([0-9]+)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(Current Song)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(pista)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(pista)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(www.[a-z]+.com.ar)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(www.[a-z]+.com)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "(www.[a-z]+.net)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "([a-z]+.com.ar)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "([a-z]+.com)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = preg_replace( "([a-z]+.net)", "", $guardardato[0]);
        $guardardato[0] = ucwords(strtolower($guardardato[0]));

        print obtener($guardardato);
    }
}
```

Comment: This work, but... i need the first value of array. Moving the function outside of `foreach`, this return all values.

Comment: If you wanted the first value of the array why would you not just `print $guardardato[0];`?

Comment: I try this, but does work, Look: http://prntscr.com/6wnoc1 http://prntscr.com/6wnokb

Comment: Oh I see what you want, try putting `break;` after `print $guardardato[0];`

Comment: Thanks thats work, and sorry for stup*d question, but this is new to me, i'm learning :)

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere! To be honest that would have confused me as well when I was new

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that obtener() is already a function defined elsewhere in your code. If you rename the function to be obtener_tema() and change the rest of the code to refer to that function, does that fix your problem?

Comment: His function is declared inside a loop, that wouldn't change much.